# Elegant way for splitting tags

Tags: java, tags, java-stream

I have a String with Tags like this

```
Car [[Best Praxis]] News Weather
```

I want to split it into a list of Strings with Entries like this:

```
Car
Best Praxis
News
Weather
```

My first approach was to do it searching for *[[* and *]]* and to spit it by this. (Like working with Sax parser) But the code will maybe ugly.

I think somehow it has to go easily by Streams but I don't find a solution how to do it with streams becasue I have these regons in brakets.

Any Idea how this task can be done easily?
Because I am pasing a tag list maybe a lib is solving this problem already or it can be solved by streams?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the following regex `(?<=\[\[)([\w\s]+)(?=]])|(\w+)` which is of the way `firstWay|secondWay`, the `|` is an `OR`

1. `(?<=\[\[)([\w\s]+)(?=]])` which means

   - `([\w\s]+)` : characters or spaces, so can be a list of words
   - `(?<=\[\[)` ensure that is prefixed by 2 oppening square brackets
   - `(?=]])` ensure that is prefixed by 2 closing square brackets
2. `(\w+)` is just a word

Giving

```
List<String> values = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\[\\[)([\\w\\s]+)(?=]])|(\\w+)")
                             .matcher("Car [[Best Praxis]] News Weather")
                             .results()
                             .map(MatchResult::group)
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(values); // [Car, Best Praxis, News, Weather]
```

### [`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/axLKtj/1)